# Display JSON data in tablular format of predefined format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working on a small project's interface. Basically, an API sends the following JSON data:

```
{
"wallet_transactions": [
    {
        "total_cost": "80.000",
        "expense_type__name": "Gas",
        "total_quantity": "5.000",
        "trans_type": "Purchased"
    },
    {
        "total_cost": "250.000",
        "expense_type__name": "Gas",
        "total_quantity": "35.000",
        "trans_type": "Rent"
    }
]}
```

The data basically shows how much of GAS was given, its cost and its means (on credit or it was bought).

I tried to build a table out of it directly, but it was dimmed unfriendly since GAS was written twice.

What I tried was:

```
$.each(response.wallet_transactions, function(index) {
    var exp_name=response.wallet_transactions[index].expense_type__name;
    var quantity=response.wallet_transactions[index].total_quantity;
    var price=response.wallet_transactions[index].total_cost;
    var trans_type=response.wallet_transactions[index].trans_type;

    rows=rows+'<tr><td>' + exp_name + '</td>';
    rows=rows + '<td>' + price + '</td>';
    rows=rows + '<td>' + quantity + '</td>';
    rows=rows + '</tr>';
});
```

The output that is needed now looks like the image below:

[image]

Comment: Will the JSON only have data for one name, or could it have multiple names with both rent and purchase for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the data for each name together in another object, then build the table from that.

```
var table_data = {};
$.each(response.wallet_transactions, function(i, trans) {
    var exp_name = trans.expense_type__name;
    var quantity = trans.total_quantity;
    var price = trans.total_cost;
    var trans_type = trans.trans_type;
    if (!table_data[exp_name]) {
        table_data[exp_name] = {}
    }
    table_data[exp_name][trans_type] = {
        quantity: quantity,
        cost: price
    };
}
$.each(table_data, function(name, data) {
    rows += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td>";
    rows += "<td>" + data.Rent.cost + "</td>";
    rows += "<td>" + data.Rent.quantity + "</td>";
    rows += "<td>" + data.Purchased.cost + "</td>";
    rows += "<td>" + data.Purchased.quantity + "</td>";
    rows += "</tr>";
}
```

Notice that `$.each` passes the array element as the second argument to the callback function, so you don't have to repeat `response.wallet_transactions[index]` on every line.